# Visual Studio Windows Form Adding Web Service Reference Error: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, wsdl, service-reference

Im trying to add wsdl web service in windows form application to connect a web service. It gives error of

"**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**"

here is the screenshot regarding the issue:

[image: screenshot]

I checked the similar questions but they didnt help. How can i get out this issue. im using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013

Any help is appreciated.